# else block for multiple ? expression in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I need else block for code below

`one?.two?.three?.four?.let {
}  // need else block here`

Is there any expression could be used this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that `let` can also return a value, so the second `run` block executes:

- if the original value is null
- if the return value is null (not what you want!)

To avoid this happening, you need to return `Unit` from the `let` block:

```
one?.two?.three?.four?.let {
    doStuff()
    Unit
} ?: run {
    doOtherStuff()
}
```

You could also use a typical `if` statement, without `?.`:

```
one?.two?.three?.four.let {
                  // ^ no ?.
    if (it == null) doStuff() else doOtherStuff()
}
```

Comment: Ok I am choosing this answer. I was looking for some gracefull way of do this but It seems not existing

Comment: @lulumeya Unfortunately, since blocks implicitly return their last expression, things like this aren't avoidable :/ I agree it seems quite clunky...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [elvis](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) operator.

Like this:

```
one?.two?.three?.four?.let {
    // if not null
} ?: run { 
    // if null
}
```

If you want call block for `null` element, then you can use [infix](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html)

```
infix fun Any?.ifNull(block: () -> Unit) {
    if (this == null) block()
}

one?.two?.three?.four ifNull {
    // Do anything
}
```

Comment: Yes the only way to approach to this case was this but I found that the codes in second block would run when the result of codes first block is null.

Comment: Do you want to execute another block after completing the first one?

Comment: No I want opposite behavior

Comment: I want to avoid case of executing both blocks at same time. If first block ends with null value, second block would also executed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I could learn about infix notation from your answer.